# How to get camunda authorization id

Tags: authorization, camunda

I am trying to create a REST application in camunda, and I want to get the default athorization id, but have no idea how to do this.
Can someone explain what should I do? It seems to me that I should send some request to the server, but I have looked up to the camunda documentation and have not found how to get authorithation id.

Comment: Hi Peter, by "authorithation id", do you mean the id of the currently logged-in user?

Comment: I have looked through camunda REST API documentation and found such a line: "GET /authorization/{id}". And as I understood {id} is an authorization id. So if this {id} is the id of a loged-in user I am interested in the method of getting this {id} on the client side. I need this to send this id as a parameter to my REST and check authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a user id before?
Can you try to create a user then give some Authorization Permission types.

Create user: `POST /user/create`

```
{"profile": 
  {"id": "jonny1",
   "firstName":"John",
   "lastName":"Doe",
   "email":"aNewEmailAddress"},
   "credentials": 
  {"password":"s3cret"}
}
```

Authorization Management: `POST /authorization/create`

```
{"type" : 0,
 "permissions": ["CREATE", "READ"],
 "userId": "*",
 "groupId": null,
 "resourceType": 1,
 "resourceId": "*"
}
```

- Permissions.READ
- Permissions.UPDATE
- Permissions.DELETE